# cplex executable not found

Tags: anaconda, cplex, pyomo, docplex

i am trying to implement a simple optimization problem in pyomo using cplex solver in UBUNTU. My program runs fine with glpk solver. Now i installed cplex, docplex using conda but got following error warning while solving. it couldnot locate cplex executable file

> **WARNING: Could not locate the 'cplex' executable, which is required for solver**
>   ERROR: Unexpected exception while running model:
>           No executable found for solver 'cplex'
>   errorcode: 1
>   retval: None

i added below lines in .bashrc file but still could'nt get the result

```
export PATH="/home/yash/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docplex:$PATH"
export PATH="/home/yash/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cplex:$PATH"
```

Comment: Can you double check that at least one of the directories you added to the `PATH` contains a cplex executable? The cplex executable may be in a sub-directory such as `bin/` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [source code](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/pyomo/solvers/plugins/solvers/CPLEX.py), we can see that `pyomo` comes with several CPLEX solver interfaces. One of these interfaces requires that the cplex "executable (i.e., the CPLEX "interactive") is in your `PATH` and I believe this is the default. However, when you install the anaconda `cplex` package you do *not* get this executable. This partially explains the error message you are getting.

If you want to use the `CPLEXSHELL` interface (i.e., the one that shells out to the CPLEX interactive), then you'll need to install one of the IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio editions (e.g., the free Community Edition) and then update your `PATH` to point at `COS_INSTALL_DIR/cplex/bin/PLATFORM` (where `COS_INSTALL_DIR` is the location you installed CPLEX Optimization Studio and `PLATFORM` is the platform you installed on (e.g., `x86-64_linux`)).

Alternatively, and I think this is what you're really trying to do, if you want to use the `pyomo` interface that connects to the CPLEX Python API, then you just need to fix your environment variables.

Instead of:

```
export PATH="/home/yash/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cplex:$PATH"
```

Try using:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/home/yash/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
```

Also, it's not entirely clear, but it almost looks like you've installed the `cplex` package into a Python virtual environment (aka, a virtualenv). If that is the case, then you just need to "activate" the virtualenv, and the `cplex` package will automatically be accessible. For example, the following might work for you:

```
cd /home/yash/anaconda3/envs/my_env/
source bin/activate
# use pyomo and cplex here
# when you're done, deactivate the virtualenv, like so:
deactivate
```

Answer (score 1):

Installing CPLEX with conda only install the python library and engine runtime for that python library. This does not install what is not necessary for the library to run.

If you are looking for the cplex executable, you want to install CPLEX Community Edition then run [installDir]/python/setup.py mentionned above by Xavier.

I think you can signup and download CPLEX CE here: https://www.ibm.com/account/reg/us-en/signup?formid=urx-20028

Answer (score 0):

Did you run
   `[installDir]/python/setup.py`
from your Python environment?