# How to set up academic version of CPLEX with anaconda in Linux?

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, cplex, docplex

I try to set up CPLEX 22.10 for use with anaconda3 (3.9.12) on Ubuntu 22.04 but

```
> python -m docplex.mp.check_list
```

always states that

```
! Cplex promotional version, limited to 1000 variables, 1000 constraints
```

Note: I have the academic version of CPLEX installed, and I can use it without restrictions with the Julia-language.

I installed CPLEX to the default folder, and ran its `setup.py` script from my anaconda path, i.e.,

```
> sudo /home/myUser/anaconda3/bin/./python "/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio221/python/setup.py" install
```

which throwed no error. Then I installed the `cplex` and `docplex` packages according to the IBM documentation, i.e.,

```
> conda install -c ibmdecisionoptimization cplex
> conda install -c ibmdecisionoptimization docplex
```

Note that I tried both: first installing the `setup.py` and then the packages, and vice versa.
In both ways the installation works with anaconda, however, with the restrictions of the promotional version mentioned above. The full output of `docplex.mp.check_list` is:

```
* system is: Linux 64bit
* Python version 3.9.12, located at: /home/myUser/anaconda3/bin/python
* docplex is present, version is 2.23.222
* CPLEX library is present, version is 22.1.0.0, located at: /home/myUser/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages
* pandas is present, version is 1.4.4
* Your cplex version 22.1.0.0 is the latest available
! Cplex promotional version, limited to 1000 variables, 1000 constraints
```

Additonally I tried to set the `PYTHONPATH` which was also unsuccessful with

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio221/python/"
```

Thank you very much for your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

please refer to [cplex executable not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56667205/cplex-executable-not-found) which may help you set your PATH so that it finds the proper cplex executable.